# What are the licence limitations on the free Ordnance Survey (OS) data sets?

Tags: data, ordnance-survey, united-kingdom, os-opendata

The OS has some “free” map data, but what am I allowed to use it for?

Comment: I voted to close this question because I do not believe that questions of legal interpretation should be entertained on this site due to potential liability for both the site and the person answering.  Asking for a link to the licence is OK, asking for interpretation is dangerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full license text is available at [the OS website](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/opendata/licence/docs/licence.pdf). Looks relatively simple - you can use it commercially if you want, but you must attribute them.

Comment: The license is similar to existing Attribution-only licenses, like CC-By. (Compatibility, on the other hand, is another issue.)

Comment: @Christopher The licence explicitly states compatibility with CC-by v3 -- see my answer for the actual text from the licence

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a question that has legal implications. If you really need to know what you can or can not do with the OS data, you need to consult a lawyer. Either that or make your own interpretation, and assume the risk that it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [OpenData licence](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/opendata/licence/docs/licence.pdf), all data can be safely assumed to be under a [CC-by 3.0 license](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/opendata/licence/docs/licence.pdf) - the T&C Explicitly say so:

> #### Creative Commons
>
> These terms have been aligned to be interoperable with any Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Licence. This means that you may mix the information with Creative Commons licensed content to create a derivative work that can be distributed under any Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Licence.

If you want to use outside of that licence, then speak to a lawyer, or read over the licence yourself